# Seek utility to find undefined classes and IDs

Tags: css

I'm looking to find a utility that shows which orphaned (CSS) classes or ids. Google lead me to a thread that ended up recommending TopStyle (http://www.highdots.com/forums/cascading-style-sheets/any-utility-list-undefined-css-188405.html).

I can afford the $70 - anyone have a better recommendation?

thx

Comment: Can you define "orphaned"? Like the elements having the id/classes and respective css not exist? Or vice versa?

Comment: The former. elements that have selectors where no CSS is defined for 'em.

Comment: @justSteve , Have you found the solution? Could you share it with us?

Answer (score 1):

Ha, actually this was in my RSS reader today. Odd timing. [Helium](http://github.com/geuis/helium-css) seems to be a JavaScript tool for doing just this. Normally I wouldn't recommend a javascript-based tool for this, but if you don't find anything else give it a go.

Comment: interesting idea but seems not to run within a IIS mvc site. And from what I can see in the docs doesn't provide a listing of which IDs/DIVs are not referenced in a stylesheet.